# type() built-in function: from python2 to python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

From Python2:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
```

from Python3:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
```

First of all, I have noticed that in python2 it returns`<type....>` while in python3 `<class....>` is it only a different way of display or is there a more deep meaning?

Second, does type function in python2 always return `instance` for object created by user-defined class?

Comment: `class A(object): pass`, `type(A)` -> `<class '__main__.A'>`, in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: so what about `<type...>` and `<class...>`? If I do `type([])` I get `<type 'list'>` in python2 while in python3 `<class 'list'>`, is there a deeper meaning?

Comment: No; Python 2 separated types and custom classes, but they were [unified  in 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/), with further refinements to the [new-style class model in 2.3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). Python 3 ditched the old-style classes altogether and tweaked the naming; `<type 'list'>` in Python 2 is exactly the same thing as `<class 'list'>` in Python 3.